# Stored procedure to format data from temp object and put in grid view

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedure.

I would like to change the format of data that I get from stored procedure. For example, a column returns a string value of `20110918190154`, I would like to change it to `2011/09/18 19:01:54`.

This is how I execute the stored procedure and return a `DataTable`:

```
   storedProcCommand = new SqlCommand("GetPurchaseHistory", conn);
   storedProcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   storedProcCommand.Parameters.Add("@customerID", cCustomerID);
   adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(storedProcCommand);
   adapter.Fill(allData);
```

Show the data in GridView as below:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView_PurchaseHistory" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
   <Columns>    
   <asp:BoundField DataField="cTranDateTime" HeaderText="Latest Purchase Date" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="cItemNo" HeaderText="Item Number" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="cDescDef" HeaderText="Description" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="fQty" HeaderText="Total Quantity" />
   </Columns> 
   </asp:GridView>
```

The output would be like:

```
Latest Purchase Date
20121007193111
20120130171010
20110918190154
```

I have written the code to substring and change the format which takes in 1 string as a time. I would like to know if there is anyway I can store the Date in a temp object and change its format accordingly.. Or if I could change before displaying it.

Thank you so much.. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: **What RDBMS?!?!?** Things like stored proedures are highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I have a list of string like below

```
List<string> dates= new List<string>();
dates.Add("20121007193111");
dates.Add("20120130171010");
dates.Add("20110918190154");
```

and a gridview like

```
<asp:gridview runat="server" ID="gvDates" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Purchase Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#ModifyDate(Container.DataItem.ToString())%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Define the ModifyDate function in code behind as below

```
public string ModifiedDate(string date)
    {
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, provider).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

Finally bind the list with the gridview

```
gvDates.DataSource = dates;
gvDates.DataBind();
```

I hope it solves your problem.